# How to add 2D array values to ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a 2d array which has data something like this,

```
categoryinfo[0][0] = {"name": "apple", "category": { "name": "fruits","id": "09a8597d"}}

categoryinfo[0][1] = {"name": "orange", "category": { "name": "fruits","id": "09a8697d"}}

categoryinfo[1][0] = {"name": "fish", "category": { "name": "meat","id": "09a8447d"}}
```

I want to display these data according to the category, As you can see the [0]the index has all the fruit items and the  [1]index has all the meat items.

I want to display these as,

### **Fruits**

Apple
Orange

### **meat**

fish

```
<table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>{{categoryinfo[0][0].category.name}}</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="formnames in categoryinfo">
        <td>{{formnames[0].name}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="formnames in categoryinfo">
        <td>{{formnames[1].name}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

to be more specific something like this above. But I cant figure out how to do this dynamically without hardcoding like this.

Comment: I don't get you `categoryinfo[0][0]`. Is it 2d Array syntax? or variable?

Comment: I just actually wanted to show that in the categoryinfo array which is a 2D array in the [0][0]th index I have the above value.

Comment: @sachin Update the sample categoryinfo array? Based on the format we can suggest

Comment: I guess this should do it, though not tried`<div ng-repeat="c in category"> <h3>{{c[0].category.name}} <p ng-repeat="list in c">{{list.name}}</h3>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2D arrays are just arrays in an array, just loop over them layer by layer will do.

```
<table>
      <thead ng-repeat-start="category in categoryinfo">
      <tr>
        <th>{{category[0].category.name}}</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat-end>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in category">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You repeat them using $index.

The first iteration iterates over y(vertical) and then the one inside gives you x(horizontal) values.

Have a look at the code below.

```js
var app = angular.module('repeatSamples', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.categoryinfo = [];
  $scope.categoryinfo[0] = []
  $scope.categoryinfo[0][0] = {
    "name": "apple",
    "category": {
      "name": "fruits",
      "id": "09a8597d"
    }
  }

  $scope.categoryinfo[0][1] = {
    "name": "orange",
    "category": {
      "name": "fruits",
      "id": "09a8697d"
    }
  }

  $scope.categoryinfo[1] = []
  $scope.categoryinfo[1][0] = {
    "name": "fish",
    "category": {
      "name": "meat",
      "id": "09a8447d"
    }
  }

  $scope.categoryinfo[1][1] = {
    "name": "mutton",
    "category": {
      "name": "meat",
      "id": "09a8447d"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body ng-app="repeatSamples" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <table class="table-bordered" ng-repeat="category in categoryinfo">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>{{category[$index].category.name}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="formnames in categoryinfo[$index]">
        <td>{{formnames.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Commented,

> I guess this should do it, though not tried `<div ng-repeat="c in category"><h3>{{c[0].category.name}} <p ng-repeat="list in c">{{list.name}}</h3>`

**Idea:**

Since you have 2-D array, you will have to use 2 loops. One to iterate over parent list and other to loop over child list.

Also since you have already grouped items based on category, you can access first element for title.

If the data structure is not fixed and you can change it, you can look into creating a hashmap. You would still need 2 loops but that might make it easier to retrieve data.

```js
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.categoryInfo = {
    fruits: [
      {"name": "apple","id": "09a8597d"},
      {"name": "orange", "id": "09a8697d"}
    ],
    meat: [
      {"name": "fish", "id": "09a8447d"}
    ]
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in categoryInfo">
    <h3>{{key}} </h3>
    <p ng-repeat="list in value">{{list.name}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Sample code:**

```js
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  var categoryInfo = [[],[]]
  categoryInfo[0][0] = {"name": "apple", "category": { "name": "fruits","id": "09a8597d"}}
  categoryInfo[0][1] = {"name": "orange", "category": { "name": "fruits","id": "09a8697d"}}
  categoryInfo[1][0] = {"name": "fish", "category": { "name": "meat","id": "09a8447d"}}
  
  $scope.categoryInfo = categoryInfo;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="c in categoryInfo">
    <h3>{{c[0].category.name}} </h3>
    <p ng-repeat="list in c">{{list.name}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```